# What is the difference between standard elastic pool DTU and premium elastic pool DTU in Azure?

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool

What performance differences are there between standard and premium DTUs in Azure elastic pools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between Standard and Premium, aside from the number of DTUs available, is the maximum I/O available per unit of DTU. The I/O per unit of DTU is orders of magnitude lower in Standard tier than in Premium tier.